# How to plot labels in the matrix diagonal?

Tags: r

I would like to know if it is possible to transfer the vertical labels in this heatmap plot to inside its diagonal indices.

```
tmp <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
tmp <-dist(tmp)
heatmap(as.matrix(tmp), Rowv = NA, Colv = NA,scale='none')
```

I would like to get something similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `image` and `text`:

```
tmp <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
tmp <-dist(tmp)
image((as.matrix(tmp)))
text(0:9/9, 0:9/9, 0:9)
```

[image]

For better control you should use `heatmap.2` from `gplots` package:

```
library(gplots)
tmp <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
tmp <-dist(tmp)
heatmap.2((as.matrix(tmp)),dendrogram = "none",
          cellnote=round(as.matrix(tmp),2),notecol='black')
```

[image]